# How can I unit test jquery dialog get displayed?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, jquery-ui-dialog, qunit, sinon

I wrote below code, try to test if a jquery dialog get excused and displayed.

```
var jqueryMock = sinon.mock(jQuery);
var dialogExpectation = jqueryMock.expects("dialog");
dialogExpectation.once();

//call my function, in which create a jquery dialog.

equals(dialogExpectation.verify(), true, "Dialog is displayed");
jqueryMock.restore();
```

However, it shows me the error:
Died on test #1: Attempted to wrap undefined property dialog as function - { "message": "Attempted to wrap undefined property dialog as function", "name": "TypeError" }

The jquery code is very simple:

```
displayMessage: function (message, title, hashId) { 

//some logic to build the message, title and hashId.  

 $(messageDiv).dialog({
            height: 240,
            width: 375,
            modal: true,
            title: title,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: [{
                text: localizedErrorMessages['OkText'],
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }]             
        }); // end of dialog            
    } // end of displayMessage
```

Anyone know how to mock the jquery dialog and write unit test in this scenario?

Comment: What testing framework is this for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mock jQuery.fn like this:

```
var jQueryMock = sinon.mock(jQuery.fn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XvP7D/) to demonstrate the working answer.

```
function displayMessage(message, title, hashId) { 

     $("#message").dialog(); 
} 

test("dialog was called", function() {

    var jQueryMock = sinon.mock($.fn); // jQuery.fn and $.fn are interchangeable
    var dialogExpectation = jQueryMock.expects("dialog");
    dialogExpectation.once();

    //call my function, in which create a jquery dialog.
    displayMessage("new message", "title", 1);

    equal(dialogExpectation.verify(), true, "Dialog was not displayed");
    jQueryMock.restore();   
});

// This demonstrates a failing test - since the method actuall calls "dialog".
// It also demonstrates a more compact approach to creating the mock
test("toggle was called", function() {

    var mock = sinon.mock(jQuery.fn).expects("toggle").once();
    displayMessage("new message", "title", 1);

    equal(mock.verify(), true, "Toggle was never called");
});
```